# Does there exist a power adapter with 2 sockets on the same continuous circuit?

Tags: electrical

I had an idea and I don't know if it is a good/safe one. My idea is inspired by recently wiring a ceiling light and a socket to turn on by the same wall switch.

We don't have a wall switch in our living room and we have 3 lamps in that room. So to turn them all on/off, I currently have them all plugged in via extension cord to an RF controlled outlet. That's fine, but I'm curious to know if this idea I had could also work:

What if one of the lamp's switches could control all the lights like the way I recently wired the ceiling light and outlet through a wall switch?

My first thought was I could splice the hot wire on one of the lamp cords and insert a 2-prong socket. Then I was like "wait, what if there was an adapter I could buy that has that splice already in it?" Like it would plug into the wall and have 2, 2-prong sockets that were wired "in series".

I know it wouldn't work unless something was plugged into each socket and turned on, but that's the idea. If I plug one lamp into one and the other 2 lamps via extension cord, I could turn on all lamps by turning on one!

Does an adapter like that exist?  I have other ideas for applications - not just lights (E.g. plug a [Switcheroo](http://www.switcheroo.com) into one of the 2 sockets).

If it could technically work, what are the drawbacks/considerations/safety-concerns? And what would be the difference compared to my in-wall wiring inspiration, if any, other than the lack of a ground (which my lamps don't have)?

I'm no electrician, but to me, it seems like it could work. I just don't know if such a wall wart exists, or if it's unsafe for any reason.

Comment: Search for “power strip controlled by master” on your favorite online purchasing place. Otherwise, this question is off-topic as a shop-for-me question.

Comment: Oh right. Yeah I didn't think of that. I just thought the electricians here would be more equipped to answer the question than anywhere else. Should I move it to a different stack?

Comment: There are lots of ways to control multiple devices with one switch.  This one is pointless, dangerous, overcomplicated and unless you use special devices designed for series wiring, like Christmas lights, and, um, pretty much nothing else, it won't even work.

Comment: @jay613 - I haven't actually shared my intended application/ultimate purpose or what my constraints are, so you're incorrect about it being "pointless" and you're incorrect in the assumption that my only constraint is to control the lights together.

Comment: Then you're asking an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).   **Don't do that**.  State your actual problem.

Comment: X is my actual question. I'm aware of what an "XY Problem" is. This is not that. I am not trying to solve Y. I am simply asking X. I already have a different solution to Y and I was simply curious about this potential answer to X for my own edification.

Comment: Hey @statueuphemism - thanks for the tip about master-controlled power strips. I wasn't using the right terms to have come across those before.  It looks like if I actually wanted to do this, from what I learned from the answers below, that would be the way to do it instead of 1 continuous circuit. I put one of those power strips on my wish list to play around with if I decide to try it out. Seems like it would address the load concerns. Too bad they don't seem to come in small 2-socket wall-wart forms.

Comment: You asked a question about controlling several lamps together.  The question was clear.  If I am incorrect in my "assumption" that you want to control lamps together, it's an XY question.

Comment: Almost every power strip has an on/off switch.  You can plug all your lamps into one and use that switch.  Is the challenge that you specifically want to control them from one of their own switches?  Can it be a new switch that you mount on one of the lamps or do your mysterious requirements dictate that the master switch be the one factory installed on one of them?

Comment: The lamps was an example. I said I have them plugged into an RF outlet which is fine. It solves that problem. What I was asking was something that was designed to learn what the difference is between a wall switch controlling 2 devices and the setup I described where a lamp switch would do the same thing. If I'd asked about other ways to turn on/off other lamps, I would not have learned about what I wanted to know and I wouldn't have learned about a master controlled power strip. I admit the question could have been crafted better, but if I had asked Y, I wouldn't have learned anything about X

Comment: I have a few unconveyed intentions/constraints. Honestly, I didn't get into them because I know everyone would try to XY that question when I'm really just trying to learn some fundamentals about electricity and I don't know what I don't know - which is why I didn't know how to ask the question well. One of them is that I'm exploring options to turn any dumb device's switch into a "reporting switch" using a second device, e.g. the switcheroo I mentioned in the question. Other devices I've tried are too slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even ignoring electrical codes and current capacity, this will not work as you intend.

You're right that the theory of electric circuits tells us that a **series circuit** can be interrupted by a switch anywhere along it. That part is fine. The problem is what happens when the switch is *on:* all of the lamps are in series!

In a **parallel circuit** (normal distribution to household outlets), every load is provided the standard line voltage, and it draws current according to how it was designed to operate (and the sum of all those currents is what the wiring back to the electrical panel and circuit breaker sees).

In a **series circuit, instead, the *voltage* is divided between the devices in some way, and the *current* is the same through the entire circuit.**

If you had a set of identical incandescent light bulbs, or identical LED bulbs with simple capacitor or resistor-based (not switchmode) power supplies, then this would merely mean that each bulb will be at most half brightness, and in practice much less than that.

If the bulbs/loads *aren't* identical, then they'll share power in some uneven fashion.

If they're using switchmode power supplies (high-efficiency LED bulbs will) then their power control circuits will interact with each other unpredictably as they take *intermittent pulses* of current from the line and thereby cause each other to lose power (when the pulse is off) repeatedly. In the unlikely event that they happen to cooperate successfully (by accident, not by design), then they *might* light up with full brightness, but this is not an intended mode of operation and might shorten the life of the bulbs.

---

Because series circuits are inconvenient like this, as a general rule, all electrical power distribution is done with parallel circuits, and series circuits exist only *within the design of individual devices,* with a few exceptions.

One exception is switches, as you've already noticed — switches go in series with a load. This is useful and safe because the switch is *fully on or fully off;* the voltage provided to the load is either full or zero.

(Notice that when you cheat a little bit, like old-school illuminated-when-off switches that put a bulb across the switch, you get side effects, like LED lights flashing due to receiving a trickle of power through the switch!)

The other notable exception is lamp dimmers (and as less of a household item, motor speed controllers). These control devices are also in series — but they work properly only with the loads that they are designed for (or that were designed for them, as with dimming-compatible LED/CFL bulbs).

Comment: It is the nature of switches to be in series. They are just interrupters, or fractional interrupters.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Yes, that is what I am discussing in that last section. Are you suggesting it is inaccurate in some way?

Comment: not at all... I'm just not used to them being described as "in series" since they're not a load.

Comment: This is a very good answer. Thanks for taking the time to provide so much detail.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very bad idea.

First of all, the cord going to the lamp, and especially the switch contacts in the lamp, are not going to be rated for the current you would need for an arbitrary load. Normal household switches (in the US) will be rated for 20 amps minimum, enough for a standard 20-amp residential circuit and more than enough for a 15-amp one, but the one in your lamp is likely rated for the load of one or two lightbulbs, a tiny fraction of an amp. It would melt, burst into flames, explode, or who knows what else under the load of, say, a space heater.

Secondly, the lamps as you state don't have a ground--so anything plugged into them would become ungrounded. This is a safety issue if you plug anything in that isn't double-insulated.

Thirdly, I'm not too familiar with electrical codes of different areas, but I'm pretty sure no matter where you are this kind of hack would be very much against electrical code, and possibly even outright illegal.

To sum it up, don't do this. There are better ways to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Ok, well that's why I asked. Regarding load, how does it differ from a wall switch that controls a ceiling light and an outlet? That's a common wiring, unless I'm mistaken. I do pass a ground, but I was planning on using strip lights in the switch-controlled outlet to light some shelving, so the ground wouldn't be involved. The load concern would be the same in that scenario, wouldn't it? I assume I'm wrong, but would like to understand why.

Comment: @hepcat72 If you're switching power through a switch, *all of the current* that whatever's plugged into it requires has to go through that switch, and that means through the lamp. Wall switches are designed to carry the full 20 amps of a standard 20-amp residential circuit (which also makes them sufficient for a 15-amp residential circuit), but whatever's in your lamp is only going to be rated to the current demand of a lightbulb or two, a tiny fraction of an amp.

Comment: Ah, that makes total sense. Thank you. I'll select your answer, but it would be nice if you add that detail.

Comment: @hepcat72 Done, sorry! Do give other people a chance to answer, I see someone else has picked up on something I missed, that you mentioned putting things in series--which would cause other problems as well.

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I was torn as soon as I saw it as to which to select.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. It adds some useful/unique detail. I wish I could have selected 2 answers. I upvoted yours though.

Answer (score 1):

Using an outlet to accept power is strictly forbidden.

You appear to be asking for an **inlet** it is an electrical fitting that accepts power instead of providing it.

[image]

This doesn't solve the whole problem if you want to use a standard lamp to control an outlet that you can connect to the inlet that feeds the overhead lights. That's possible using a current-operated switch like found in "energy saving" power strips.

Answer (score 1):

### Your fundamental problem is lack of a proper light switch

A variety of building codes require that every habitable room have a light switch.  It must be in one of the "usual locations". By "usual", I mean a location that anyone new to the room will automatically reach for.  You know the ones!

The light switch must operate either a) a light built into the ceiling/walls, or b) switch one or more receptacle(s) into which light(s) are plugged in.

That's a Code requirement and you need to retrofit it (or I suspect, *restore* something you had previously removed).

If you want to accomplish this with a physical "wireless light switch" in the usual location, which controls smart lamps or modules via smart tech... that is acceptable **if it works**.

There are a variety of products which will do that thing for you.

Modifying equipment or building ad-hoc wiring, and certainly, wiring lights in series (which won't work) is dangerous and unnecessary given that what you need is readily available.

Comment: The lamp example is actually just an example. I have not stated what my ultimate goal/intent is. That's a whole other question. That said, you make some good points about my living room. I don't know what the electrical codes were in 1920 when this house was built, but I haven't changed any switches/fixtures. Although, the previous owner was an electrician and did a lot of rewiring. I wonder if he took out or repurposed a switch. He ran electric out to the detached garage though, and that's awesome.